# Capitalization rules for nicknames and name-replacing honorifics

Tags: capitalization, nicknames, honorifics

My intuition is to capitalize any word that used in reference to a person in place of their name: *Mother, Father, Grandma, Grandpa, Doctor, Captain, Professor, Sir, Ma’am, Boss,* etc. But my research seems to indicate some of these are proscribed: *sir* is capitalized only when it's being prepended to the name of a knight, and *ma'am* is never capitalized.

What’s the rule—or, if guidance differs, what *are* the *rules*—here?

I am *not* asking about cases where one of these words is used with an article such as *the*. In these cases, the standard seems to be no capitalization: *the* doctor, *the* captain, *the* professor. Nor am I asking about the case where one of these words is prepended to a name as is the chivalric *Sir* mentioned above. In these cases, capitalization seems standard: *Doctor* Jones, *Captain* Smith, *Professor* Brown.

What I’m wondering is this: what makes the *sir* in “yes, sir” any different from the *Dad* in “hi, Dad”? They’re both titles used in place of someone’s name, but one is capitalized and the other isn’t—what rule governs that? And which side of this rule do things like the *C/captain* in “aye aye, C/captain” fall onto?

Is it that *sir* is normally only used in vocative address, whereas *Dad* is also used in third-person reference?

According to [Capitalizing Personal Titles as Substitutes for Names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447563/capitalizing-personal-titles-as-substitutes-for-names), at least some style guides recommend say that formal titles like *chancellor* and *chairman* should be capitalized only if they precede a name... but what about *Father* as used in vocative address to a Catholic priest? If it’s capitalized, it’s an exception because it violates this rule; but if it’s *not* capitalized, it’s an exception because it’s an (albeit fictive) kinship term, and kinship terms are universally capitalized in the vocative.

Comment: 'Sir' isn't a title in 'Good morning, sir'. If you would capitalise 'Doctor' in 'Doctor Smith', why not 'Father' in 'Father Brown'?

Comment: You may well find *Sir* used as third-person, "I gave it to Sir," although this might not be classed as Standard English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Remember "To Sir With Love"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I’m not asking about the “Father” in the phrase “Father Brown”. I'm asking about the case where you’re confessing to him and say, “Forgive me, F/father, for I have sinned.” This is a tricky case because it is both a non-prenominal use of a prenominal title (which many style guides say should not be capitalized) and a kinship term (which is pretty much universally capitalized).

Comment: @Barmar That's a bit different because it's styled after a letter salutation, and those use special rules (cf. "Dear Sir or Madam").

Comment: @Barmar I'm not that old :-)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/618775/2085).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this blog](http://www.grammarlandia.com/2016/07/capitalization-honorifics-and-yo-mama.html)... yes, guidance differs. "Those of you looking for hard and fast rules on this issue are doomed to disappointment." But let's agree, for starters, that it all hinges on *direct address*. If you side with the up-stylers, you capitalize *Padré* when addressing the priest *because you're addressing him*, and would still capitalize it if you wanted to call him "Dude." (At this point, my inner conflict between the stickler and the realist comes to blows over "Hey, You!")

It also notes, "For reasons lost in the mists of time (or at least not immediately findable on the Internet)" words like "sir," "ma'am," or "m'lady" are never capitalized. Trying to track down an explanation does indeed yield an amusing array of confused and clearly false answers. If I had to guess it would simply be that familiarity breeds contempt, and such addresses have been bandied about for so long that we can't take the time to capitalize them (let alone provide all the letters).